# How can I mark an Azure Dataset as a time series dataset reading from a parquet folder with date partitions?

Tags: parquet, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to create a Time series dataset from a folder that contains parquet files this way:

- timestamp=2018-01-06
- timestamp=2018-01-07

How can I make Azure Dataset, through the GUI, recognises the timestamp partition as a date and mark my dataset as a time series dataset?

It is supposed to be automatic, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It works well when doing it through Python code, but not through the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out to us.

In Azure Machine Learning Studio, you would need to setup partition format similar to python SDK, as follows, assuming your data path is "timeseries/timestamp=2020-01-01/data.parquet":
[Set up partition format when creating time series dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwYfF.png)

Comment: It works well for the Python SDK, but not well through the GUI.